# In azure can we update the profile.ps1 file function app?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

We have a function in azure portal. When we create function app, we can see the profile.ps1 in App Files section of a function App. Can we edit this profile.ps1 file using PowerShell or CLI commands. If Yes, please help me out.

Any help can be appriciated...!

Comment: Any update this issue? Without any reply, I believe I will not look into your questions in the future again.

Comment: I have tried in different way. When we create function app new store account will be created which associate to that function app. In storage account file share we can see this profile.ps1. if we make any changes to this file automatically the file in function app will get update

Comment: Yes, it is also a feasible way, but it does not prevent you to accept another correct answer, you can also share your solution as an answer, then it can benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your option is to use [Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs) via powershell to update the `profile.ps1`, in my sample, I store the new `profile.ps1` with the path `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\profile.ps1` in local, it works fine on my side.

Sample:

```
$appsvWebAppName = "<functionapp-name>"
$resourceGroupName = "<group-name>"

$resource = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "$appsvWebAppName/publishingcredentials" -Action list -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force

$username = $resource.Properties.publishingUserName
$password = $resource.Properties.publishingPassword
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"


$apiUrl = "https://$appsvWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/profile.ps1"
$filePath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\profile.ps1"
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + $base64AuthInfo
    'If-Match' = '*'
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -UserAgent $userAgent -Method PUT -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]